# How do I remove a Link in dom selector in following script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the following code to avoid refresh of links, but I have few links using Omniauth like facebook login, google login and twitter login, so I don't want to use this script for those links. How can I remove those links from this script. It is ruby on rails app.

```
   $(function(){
        var newHash      = '',
            $mainContent = $("#main-content");
        $(".nav").delegate("a","click",function(){
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
            return false;
        });
        $(window).bind('hashchange',function(){
            newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            if(newHash){
                $mainContent.find("#guts").fadeOut('slow',function(){
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts",function(){
                        $mainContent.fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                });
            }

        });
        $(window).trigger("hashchange");
    });
```

Comment: what is `hello` in `'a:not("hello")'` ??

Comment: @TusharGupta sorry about that was trying few things

Comment: okay which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: are links loaded dynamically and that's why using `delegate`?

Comment: don't understand why you don't just let browser set the hash when link clicked, you rather set it using `window.location.hash`...why?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, the links are being loaded dynamically, Using this I am trying to avoid refreshing the header of the page.

Comment: I am following this http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/

Answer (score 0):

can do something like this

```
$(".nav").delegate("a","click",function(e){
       if (this.hash ){
           e.preventDefault();
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");           
       }

      /* other links with no hash work normally*/
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b93tM/)**</kbd>

Comment: I also have modal popup, for which I have to disable this

Comment: need more details then...modal shouldn't have hash does it? If it's just `#` can change to `if (this.hash && this.hash !='#' ){`

Comment: this.hash what does it check ? its always returning false

Comment: `hash` is the part of url like `#foobar`. Post samples of link href. Similar to what you are using `window.location.hash`...only it is also property of an `<a>` tag